# Change css for every 4th row

Tags: php, css

I want to display every 4th row grabbed from the database with different CSS style. The first three rows from the DB should take the CSS style (col-4) but the fourth row should take the CSS style (col-4 last): How can I do this with PHP. My code is showing below.

```
<?php foreach($result as $value) : ?>
    <div class="col-4">
        <a href="view.php?m_id=<?php echo $value['m_id']; ?>">
            <img alt="" src="<?php echo $value['m_image']; ?>" width="131px" height="120px">
        </a>
        <h3><a href="view.php?m_id=<?php echo $value['m_id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['m_title']; ?></a></h3>
        <p><strong><?php echo $value['name']; ?></strong> </p>
        <p><?php echo date('M j, g:i A', strtotime($value['date'])); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650337/how-to-use-modulus-with-php-to-add-a-css-class-to-a-grid-of-images-depending-on

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this with the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) CSS selector:

```
.col-4:nth-child(4n) {
    /* styles for every 4th row */
}
```

If you do not want to style *every* 4th row but instead *only* the 4th row, do not use the `n` in `4n`:

```
.col-4:nth-child(4) { ... }
```

[Browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) is not bad at all; everything except IE < 9 is supported.

Comment: *Everything except IE < 9*, of course. Plan for the worse, I always say. `$worse=IE;` lol (**+1**) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use PHP at all; CSS provides this functionality on its own.

```
.col-4 { 
    ..... your standard css for the columns ...... 
}
.col-4:nth-child(4) { 
    ..... your special css for the 4th column
}
```

Alternatively, if the 4th element is the last one in the set (as you hinted in the question), you could use `col-4:last-child { ... }` instead.

Browser compatibility note: If you need to support IE8 or earlier with these selectors, you will need to use a CSS polyfill script such as [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com), since older IE versions don't support it. Selectivizr deals with that problem nicely though.

Answer (score 1):

Simply count how many rows you have outputted and use the modulus to check whether it is a 4th row:

```
$index = 0;
<?php foreach($result as $value) : ?>
    <div class="col-4<?php if (++$index % 4 == 0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
        <a href="view.php?m_id=<?php echo $value['m_id']; ?>">
            <img alt="" src="<?php echo $value['m_image']; ?>" width="131px" height="120px">
        </a>
        <h3><a href="view.php?m_id=<?php echo $value['m_id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['m_title']; ?></a></h3>
        <p><strong><?php echo $value['name']; ?></strong> </p>
        <p><?php echo date('M j, g:i A', strtotime($value['date'])); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($result as $i=>$value) : ?>
    <div class="col-4<? if ($i%4==3) echo ' last'; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div:nth-child(4n)
```

use nth-child with multiplicator in css

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Asked also here: [Select every Nth element in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css)